# Format number to show eg. "27.0 °C" using query and/or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, format, numbers, decimal

A few friends and I are trying to do a minor IoT project, where the controls are handled on a website, to be used on mobiles.

So basically, we have a range slider, used to control the desired temperature in a room. An Arduino does the actual handling of the temperature from there. We have got hold on the database, communication between Arduino and database, but we can't handle this problem ourselves.

We found the javascript code, (as seen below) on [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/pre_developer/1929444).

Right now, the sliders work fine and shows the value selected. What we want is to format the number so it shows **1** decimal and includes the ending " **°C**" So in stead of "26" it shows **"26.0 °C".**

I have excluded the non-important classes related to bootstrap in the HTML-code below, to give a better overview.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <form method="post">
        <span class="valueSpan"></span>
        <input id="slider11" name="temp_sub" value="<?php echo $temp; ?>" step="0.5" type="range" min="10" max="35" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  const $valueSpan = $('.valueSpan');
  const $value = $('#slider11');
  $valueSpan.html($value.val());
  $value.on('input change', () => {

    $valueSpan.html($value.val());
  });
});
</script>
```

**Photo:**

[image: Photo of range slider for temperature]

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed() and add ºC

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  const $valueSpan = $('.valueSpan');
  const $value = $('#slider11');
  $valueSpan.html($value.val());
  $value.on('input change', () => {

    $valueSpan.html((+$value.val()).toFixed(1) + 'ºC');
  }).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form method="post">
    <span class="valueSpan"></span>
    <input id="slider11" name="temp_sub" value="20" step="0.5" type="range" min="10" max="35" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

It workes perfectly!

As I mentioned, we are far from experts, but your reply truly helped a lot!